# Why is Modal Popup with Jekyll and bootsratp only showing content of last child?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jekyll, modalpopup

I am trying to build a modal popup using jekyll and bootstrap. The problem is every popup only displays the last child in loop info, instead of that specific child. Ive tried a few different ideas out to fix this issue but I cant seem to figure it out.

Below is some of the code I have for the project im working on. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

HTML:

```
{% for stone in site.data.stones %}

<div class="popup-content">
  <h1>{{ stone.color }}</h1>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="popup-hold">
  <h1>{{ stone.gem }}</h1>
  <button class="open">Open</button>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

CSS:

```
.popup-overlay {
   visibility: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   background: grey;
   height: 50%;
   width: 50%;
   left: 25%;
}

.popup-overlay.active {
   visibility: visible;
   z-index: 1;
}

.popup-content {
   visibility: hidden;

}

.popup-content.active {
   visibility: visible;
   z-index: 1;
}

.popup-hold {
   height: 330px;
   border: 2px solid black;
}
```

stones.yml:

```
- gem: Mind
  color: yellow

- gem: Time
  color: green

- gem: Soul
  color: orange
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 // adds "active" class to overlay and content
  $(".open").on("click", function(){
    $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").addClass("active");
  });
  // removes "active" class from overlay and content
  $(".close, .popup-overlay").on("click", function(){
    $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: Assuming your html has all the stones, then this is a jquery issue and I'd be looking at your function.  I don't know jquery (or even really vanilla js), but perhaps see if when you fire a click event you are adding .active to all your stones - no matter which is clicked - such that all "display" but the last (being "on top") is always seen?

Comment: Yes every modal I open, the popup only shows the info of the last child in loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have not given us the full picture - so it is hard to help.

However, I ***suspect*** there are two (2) different problems.

**FIRST: No Opening `<div class="pop-overlay>` in jekyll loop.**

Change your liquid loop to include the opening div for each stone's overlay:

```
{% for stone in site.data.stones %}

<div class="popup-overlay"> // Add this opening div
  <div class="popup-content">
    <h1>{{ stone.color }}</h1>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup-hold">
  <h1>{{ stone.gem }}</h1>
  <button class="open">Open</button>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

You may need to remove any lone opening div before the loop in your code - if you have a div for that.

**SECOND: Get jquery to ONLY open the related (previous) modal**

This problem is that your jquery is opening ALL modals on the page - whichever `.open` button you click.

You may only ***see*** the last one because it is "on top" of the other modals - depending on your styling.

Try changing your jquery so that when you click on the `.open` button, only the preceding/associated modal element is opened (as opposed to all of them).

Try something like this jquery instead:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 // adds "active" class to overlay and content
  $(".open").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().prev(".popup-overlay").addClass("active");
    $(this).parent().prev(".popup-overlay").find(".popup-content").addClass("active");
  });
  // removes "active" class from overlay and content
  $(".close").on("click", function(){
    $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").removeClass("active");
  });
});
</script>
```

NOTE: This script will shut down all open modals when any of the close buttons are clicked.

If you want to only shut down the related modal, then you will need to change the closing action similar to what we have done with the opening action - i.e. by only selecting the related modal.

I have had to make guesses about how you have set things up, but I hope this helps.

If this doesn't work, then you should provide the full output html or better working example.

Here is a demo of how I ***THINK*** you sort of want it to run:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  // adds "active" class to overlay and content
  $(".open").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().prev(".popup-overlay").addClass("active");
    $(this).parent().prev(".popup-overlay").find(".popup-content").addClass("active");
  });
  // removes "active" class from overlay and content
  $(".close").on("click", function() {
    $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
  .popup-overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: grey;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}

.popup-overlay.active {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 1;
}

.popup-content {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.popup-content.active {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 1;
}

.popup-hold {
  height: 330px;
  border: 2px solid black;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="popup-overlay">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <h1>yellow</h1>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup-hold">
  <h1>Mind</h1>
  <button class="open">Open</button>
</div>


<div class="popup-overlay">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <h1>Green</h1>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup-hold">
  <h1>Time</h1>
  <button class="open">Open</button>
</div>


<div class="popup-overlay">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <h1>Orange</h1>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup-hold">
  <h1>Soul</h1>
  <button class="open">Open</button>
</div>
```